# Why is Tensorflow autoencoder example code not producing reasonable decoded images?

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, autoencoder

I am running the example (tutorial) code for a basic autoencoder from tensorflow.org [autoencoder tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/autoencoder?hl=en) on my M1 Max MBP. It is all running fine (using GPU and everything) but the resultant (decoded) images from the latent space don't look anything like the original images.

Here's the exact code I ran, but it was copied directly off the website:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras import layers, losses
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import fashion_mnist
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255.
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255.

latent_dim = 64 

class Autoencoder(Model):
  def __init__(self, latent_dim):
    super(Autoencoder, self).__init__()
    self.latent_dim = latent_dim   
    self.encoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
      layers.Flatten(),
      layers.Dense(latent_dim, activation='relu'),
    ])
    self.decoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
      layers.Dense(784, activation='sigmoid'),
      layers.Reshape((28, 28))
    ])

  def call(self, x):
    encoded = self.encoder(x)
    decoded = self.decoder(encoded)
    return decoded

autoencoder = Autoencoder(latent_dim)

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=losses.MeanSquaredError())
```

Training the model, encoding and decoding:

```
autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,
                epochs=10,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(x_test, x_test))

encoded_imgs = autoencoder.encoder(x_test).numpy()
decoded_imgs = autoencoder.decoder(encoded_imgs).numpy()
```

Training results:

```
Epoch 1/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 9s 5ms/step - loss: 0.0276 - val_loss: 0.0161
Epoch 2/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 8s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0142 - val_loss: 0.0131
Epoch 3/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 8s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0126 - val_loss: 0.0126
Epoch 4/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 8s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0123 - val_loss: 0.0125
Epoch 5/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 8s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0123 - val_loss: 0.0126
Epoch 6/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 8s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0124 - val_loss: 0.0130
Epoch 7/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 7s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0126 - val_loss: 0.0127
Epoch 8/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 8s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0127 - val_loss: 0.0129
Epoch 9/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 8s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0129 - val_loss: 0.0133
Epoch 10/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 7s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0131 - val_loss: 0.0135
```

[Tensorflow autoencoder output image from my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SosR8.png).

[Tensorflow autoencoder output image from tensorflow.org](https://www.tensorflow.org/static/tutorials/generative/images/intro_autoencoder_result.png)

I also tried changing the latent space dimensions from 64 up to 392 and increasing the number of epochs for training (up to 20) but the results didn't change much. I also ran the same code on an Intel iMacPro and got similar results, so I don't think it's an ARM64 thing.

Why does the identical tutorial code run on my computer produce an output that doesn't look anything like the original or what is expected based on the results from the tensorflow website? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT 2023-07-27

I also just confirmed that the same code in Google Colab produces reasonable decoded images. On my Macs I use a conda environment from a yaml file with the following:

```
name: tf_env 
channels:
   - conda-forge
   - defaults 
dependencies:
   - python=3.10
   - tensorflow
   - pip
   - jupyterlab
   - pandas
   - numpy
   - matplotlib
   - scikit-learn
   - scipy
   - plotly
   - pip:
     - tensorflow-metal
```

The versions reported from `conda list` are:

```
keras                     2.12.0
keras-preprocessing       1.1.2
ml_dtypes                 0.2.0
numpy                     1.25.1
python                    3.10.12
scikit-learn              1.3.0
tensorflow                2.12.1
tensorflow-base           2.12.1
tensorflow-estimator      2.12.1
tensorflow-metal          1.0.0
```

EDIT #2

**I have tracked the problem down to the `tensorflow-metal` package** which was installed using pip. When this package was removed (using `pip uninstall tensorflow-metal`) and the code was run using CPUs, the output looked as expected. Reinstalling `tensorflow-metal` returned the poor performance. Interestingly, this also occurred on an Intel Mac. I am posting a link to this in Apple's Developer Forum to see if anyone there has any ideas.

Comment: From the training status, it looks like the network is heavily overfitting. If you check your `val_loss` it is not decreasing at all. I copied your code and trained on google colab but I'm getting similar results to what's posted on the website. Can you check if you are using the latest `sklearn`, `numpy` and `tensorflow` versions?

Comment: Added relevant version info to main post.